# XML/DTD The content of element type "Movie" must match "(Title,Price)". [7]

Tags: xml, dtd

Hoping someone can point out the error here - its only an example piece I am trying, but I just cannot get the XML to parse.....

The DTD looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT Movies (Movie*)>
<!ELEMENT Movie (Title, Price)>
<!ATTLIST Movie year CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT Title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Price (#PCDATA)>
```

And the sample XML looks like this
(I can't stop the preview from interpreting the XML!!)

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Movies SYSTEM "movies.dtd">
<Movies>
    <Movie year="1946">
        <Title>It’s a Wonderful Life</Title>
        <Price>14.95</Price>
    </Movie>
    <Movie year="1965">
        <Title>The Great Race</Title>
        <Price>12.95</Price>
    </Movie>
    <Movie year="1974">
        <Title>Young Frankenstein</Title>
        <Price>16.95</Price>
    </Movie>
    <Movie year="1975">
        <Title>The Return of the Pink Panther</Title>
        <Price>11.95</Price>
    </Movie>
</Movies>
```

And the error I get is ...

The content of element type "Movie" must match "(Title,Price)".

for every 'Movie' entry in the database I'm hoping it is something stupid - 'cos I can't see it!

Thanks

Comment: The only problem I see is the presence of the XML declaration in the DTD file.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

XML version should be 1.0-:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

and final closing tag `</Movies>` missing - probably just missed pasting this onto the post.

Comment: Yep - its there in the original, just didn't appear in the post - sorry. I'll try the 1.0

Answer (score 0):

OK - no other responses but I found the problem.

It was down to formatting of the XML file. I was a bit surprised, but I stripped out all line endss etc and everything was fine.